# How to display error message if the user clicks on second tab before filling the data of the first tab

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-tabs

On button click, four bootstrap tabs are displayed and by default first tab information is displayed.

But if the user clicks on the second tab instead of filling the information in the first tab an error message should be displayed and he should not be allowed to click on any of the tabs unless he fills the information in the first tab.

After filling the required information on the first tab he should be directed to the second tab and the information  filled by the user in the first tab should be saved in the database on click of save button, which is there on the first tab.

Comment: Hi, you wanna just that the form is filled or validate ?

Comment: This is a general broad requirement. Can you share your code so far?

Comment: Have a look at http://formvalidation.io/examples/fuel-ux-wizard/

Comment: no only the form filled

Comment: @Ninad ok so check the answer I wrote a custom code for check if filled or not.

Answer (score 0):

For answer your question I just wrote a simple snippet where you can get when the form is filled or not.

inside isValid, true or false you can run all your custom code.

For enable disabled the bootstrap form I just removed or add the 'data-toggle="tab"' without add class or other css.

For check if the form is filled I added a class "required" for the fields that you want to controll and wrote a function where check 'on click' event if that fields are not null.

**Alternatively** if you want to implement a ready plugin for validate your form and spend less time to code your custom code well check this link

http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-wizard/

```js
function validateForm() {
  
  var isValid = true;
  $('#installationForm .form-group .required').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
        isValid = false;
  });
  return isValid;

}

$('.next-tab').on('click', function(event) {
    var result = validateForm();
  if (result) {
    $('.next a').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
    
  } else {
      $('.next a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    alert('You have to fill the form before!');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form id="installationForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#basic-tab" data-toggle="tab">Site information</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a class="next-tab" href="#database-tab" data-toggle="tab">Database</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- First tab -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="basic-tab">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Site name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="required form-control" name="name" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">URL</label>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <input type="text" class="required form-control" name="url" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Owner email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="required form-control" name="email" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <textarea class="required form-control" name="description" rows="6"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Second tab -->
        <div class="tab-pane" id="database-tab">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Server IP</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dbServer" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Database name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dbName" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Database user</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dbUser" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="dbPassword" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Previous/Next buttons -->
        <ul class="pager wizard">
            <li class="previous"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Previous</a></li>
            <li class="next"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="completeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Complete</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-center">The installation is completed</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Visit the website</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just used a class "required" for check you can use any class that you like.

Comment: @Ninad you asked to enable the tab only if the form is filled. Well check the field value by a classname... I called "required" you can call 'field'  or how you like. checking the field value you can decide too which field have to be filled or not for enable the tab.